# cloning a form with jquery and remove attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to clone a form without disturbing the functionality ?
Indeed, the id of the form will be duplicate. Two DOM objects with the same id is forbidden.

```
<form id='originalForm' name='originalForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>  
   <input id='Firstname' name='firstname' type='text'/>  
   <input id='Lastname' name='lastname' type='text' />  
   <input id='photo' name='photo' type='file' />
</form>  
...  
var copyForm = jQuery('#originalForm').clone();  
var e = copyForm.find(':input').not(':file');
e.each(function()  
{
  jQuery($this).removeAttr('name');
}
```

Comment: You can change id after clone:  
var copyForm = jQuery('#originalForm').clone();  
copyForm.attr('id, 'newForm');

Comment: @PiotrUchman you already had the answer. Was there a reason for adding it as a comment rather than an answer? Am just curious.

Comment: I think, that the answer has to be more informative. It was rather quick tip in my opinion. And I was too lazy to write about children elements ids :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var originalForm = jQuery('#originalForm');
//clone the form
var newForm = originalForm.clone(); 
//change form ID
newForm.attr('id', 'newID'); 
//remove `name` attr from all non file inputs
newForm.find('input:not(:file)').removeAttr('name'); 
//add new form to the page after the old one
originalForm.after(newForm);
```

Comment: id's of children controls of newform and old form still remains same... couldn't be conflict???

Comment: That seems very easy ! How to clone or append the uploaded photo which is in an iframe ?

Comment: @maverickosama92 ehhh. It _could_. But if you do `newForm.find('#FirstName')` you will get different results than if you do `originalForm.find('#FirstName')`